# Regex on VB.Net to get only first few numbers from left to right

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am pretty new on regular expressions, but as far as I've been wandering around Google, the only thing I could do to solve my problem is through regex.

I have a collection of strings which have patterns like these:

"3 - Orange, Lemon"
"4 - Pineapple, Orange"
"12 - Lime, Strawberry"

My current code is:

```
Private Sub cmbKelas_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbKelas.SelectedIndexChanged
        LblID.Text = cmbKelas.Text
End Sub
```

Which gives output to entire string.. what I wanted is that cmbKelas.Text will have its value stripped so each string will changes into:

"3"
"4"
"12"

Only the first few numbers. A comment, suggestion, or point to the right links/articles would help because so far I couldn't manage to find a decent tutorials that easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with Regular Expressions you could use something like this:

```
Dim ResultString As String
ResultString = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "^\d+").Value
```

Where SubjectString would be the string you are searching in.

Explanation (since you are new to regex):

- The `^` signifies the beginning of a string (that why you don't match
  number that are not at the beginning)
- `\d` signifies a digit 0-9
  (it's the short form of [0-9] which would do the same)
- and `+` means
  that the character prior to `+` will be matched at least once.

That way you will match 1 to infinite digits at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Regex is overkill for this task.

You can use the [`IndexOf` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) to figure out where the first space occurs and then use the [`Substring` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) to take the beginning of the string up to the index of the first space.

```
Dim values As String() = New String() { _
    "3 - Orange, Lemon", _
    "4 - Pineapple, Orange", _
    "12 - Lime, Strawberry" _
}

For Each input as String In values
    Dim number As String = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(" "))
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
```

Alternately, you could use the [`Split` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to split on spaces and take the first item in the split result array as follows:

```
For Each input as String In values
    Dim split As String() = input.Split(" "c)
    Dim number As String = split(0)
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
```

Comment: I'm partial for the split option myself, that way if you need to get the values down the road (and potentially get individual values split based off the comma) you're already one step there.

Comment: @Dillie-O I agree. It's certainly a better approach if other data is needed, rather than using `IndexOf` for multiple parts of the string.

Comment: Though its somehow not working on my code (maybe it has something to do with imports system.*.*), but this approach sounds simpler, I will keep it for later use..

Comment: @Natasha these methods are part of the `System` namespace, which is typically there by default (`Imports System`). Also make sure you're assigning the result of `Substring` or `Split` to a variable (as I've done) or property since strings are immutable; the string methods return a new string, they don't affect the original string object.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [`SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), you could use [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
Dim numbers = new List(Of String)()
For Each input as String In values
    Dim parts = input.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    If (parts.Length > 0) Then
        numbers.Add(parts[0])
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The same as substring, its not working on my code, but thank you very much for the help, I will keep the syntax for later use next time I needed it.. thank you

Comment: @Natasha Illyasviel: Although you now have a solution, could you elaborate on what isn't working with this solution: do you get an error? We could still get you a potentially less expensive way of doing this.

Comment: Because i use it on non Array, I modified it into :<br/><pre>Dim parts As String
        parts = cmbKelas.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c})</pre><br/><br/>the error was : "value of type 1-dimensional array can not be converted to string"

Comment: @Natasha Illyasviel: Oh, I see, you have a single string containing all of these elements - in that case you may want to split into segments of full expected strings and _then_ carry out the manipulation, on the other hand you might just want to stick with regex. ;)

Comment: @Natasha Illyasviel: Ah, with your updated comment: did you try to assign the result to anything, an existing variable, for instance? You see, `parts` is not a single string like its input, but an array of resulting strings, and `numbers` will be a list of strings.