# How to display the numeric numbers

Tags: vb.net

Here's the content of my DataGrid

```
id

1
2
3A
4
5
6A
..
...
10V1
```

I want to get the max number from the datagrid. Then, I want to 
display the next number (In this case: 11) in the textbox beside the grid

Expected Output

```
id

1
2
3A
4
5
6A
..
...
10V1
11
```

I tried the following code:

```
textbox1.text = gridList.Rows(gridlist.RowCount() - 1).Cells(1).Value + 1
```

It works if the previous row values is entirely numeric. However, if the value is alpahnumeric, I am getting the following error:

```
Conversion from string "10V1" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

Can someone help me solve this problem? I am looking for a solution in `VB.Net`

Comment: If the values are always in the format `<Number>` or `<Number><Character><Number>`, or even `<Number><Something else>`, just split the string on the first non-numeric character, and add 1 to that.

Comment: Are the numbers always from 1 to `Number of rows` (in this case: 10)? If so, you could use: `textbox1.text = gridList.RowCount() + 1`

Comment: @Msonic, i cannot take the rowcount, because user can able to remove the rows in between, then it will give the wrong no...

Comment: @ LittleBobbyTables , can you give some example or more clarification plz..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into `Regex` to do that (based on what I understand from your question)

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066150/regex-on-vb-net-to-get-only-first-few-numbers-from-left-to-right) on this.

`Regex.Match` will return the part of the string that will match the expression... In your case, you want the first number in your string (Try `"^\d+"` as your expression, it will find any serie of numbers at the beginning of your string). You can then convert the result string into an `int` and add 1 to it.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Here's more info on [regex expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).